# Ionic 6-React custom font does not change on android

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react, ionic6

I'm trying to change the entire app font to a custom font like so

[image]

Bringing it to my variables like so

[image]

Applying to global.css like this

[image]

[image]

Does not change on android, it still uses Roboto font. But, it works in the browser.

[image]

The Browser version

Comment: do you found a solution?, i have the same problem